# Generic Singleton Pattern using Reflection, in C#

Tags: c#

I try to code a Generic Singleton Pattern in c# to auto configuration by reading json file

```
public sealed class ConfigManager<T> where T : class
{
    readonly string name = $"{nameof(T).ToString().ToLower()}.Json";
    private ConfigManager() { }

    private static readonly ConfigManager<T> _instance;

    public static ConfigManager<T> Instance => _instance;
    public static ConfigManager<T> GetInstance()
    {         
            if (File.Exists(nameof(name)))
                _instance.Load();
            _instance.Create();
            return _instance;           
    }

    public T Config { get; set; }

    public void Load()
    {
        Config = new();
        using var stream = File.OpenRead(name);
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(T)) as T;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        Config = new();
        using var stream = File.OpenWrite(name);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(stream, Config, typeof(T));
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        Config = new();
        using FileStream createFile = File.Create(name);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(createFile, Config, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

but i'm not sure how to create

i try use reflection on singleton generic

Comment: This code looks almost complete, and you know how to use new operator. What's your problem? Why reflection?

Comment: I don't see a Singleton pattern here. Looks more like a factory. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @shingo i don't know how to use new operator in there, can u explain me?

Comment: `_instance = new();`